# Getting an error trying to use an interface in an async task

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am getting an error on this line here:

```
task.setOnArticleSelectedListener(this);
```

The error I am getting is:

```
setOnArticleSelectedListener
(com.beerportfolio.beerportfoliopro.PortfolioGetAllBeers.OnArticleSelectedListener)
in PortfolioGetAllBeers cannot be applied
to
(android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener)
```

That code comes out of:

```
public class Portfolio extends Fragment implements PortfolioGetAllBeers.OnArticleSelectedListener {

    String beerId = "";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //set layout here
        final View theLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_portfolio, container, false);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        getActivity().setTitle("Style");

        //get user information
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        String userName = prefs.getString("userName", null);
        String userID = prefs.getString("userID", null);

        final Spinner portfolioType = (Spinner) theLayout.findViewById(R.id.portfolioSpinner);
        portfolioType.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {


            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {

                String portfolioChoice = portfolioType.getSelectedItem().toString();


                Log.d("portfolio", portfolioChoice);

                if( portfolioChoice.equals("All")){


                    //todo: clear second spinner
                    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) theLayout.findViewById(R.id.addSpinnerLayout);
                    ll.removeAllViews();

                    //get userID
                    //get user data
                    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(selectedItemView.getContext());
                    String userID = prefs.getString("userID", null);

                    //construct url
                    String url = "myURL";


                    //async task goes here
                    PortfolioGetAllBeers task = new PortfolioGetAllBeers(getActivity());
                    task.setOnArticleSelectedListener(this);
                    task.execute(url);

                }

                else if (portfolioChoice.equals("Brewery")){

                    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) theLayout.findViewById(R.id.addSpinnerLayout);
                    ll.removeAllViews();
                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)selectedItemView.getContext().getSystemService(selectedItemView.getContext().LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.addspinner_layout, null); // inflate addspinner
                    Spinner sp = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.portfolioSpinner2); //portfolioSpinner2
                    ll.addView(v); // add the view to the linear layout

                    //todo: get breweries and fill spinner
                    //get userID
                    //get user data
                    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(selectedItemView.getContext());
                    String userID = prefs.getString("userID", null);

                    //construct url
                    String url = "myURL2";


                    //async task goes here
                    new PortfolioGetAllBreweries(selectedItemView.getContext()).execute(url);

                }


                else if (portfolioChoice.equals("Style")){

                    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) theLayout.findViewById(R.id.addSpinnerLayout);
                    ll.removeAllViews();
                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)selectedItemView.getContext().getSystemService(selectedItemView.getContext().LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.addspinner_layout, null); // inflate addspinner
                    Spinner sp = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.portfolioSpinner2); //portfolioSpinner2
                    ll.addView(v); // add the view to the linear layout

                    //get userID
                    //get user data
                    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(selectedItemView.getContext());
                    String userID = prefs.getString("userID", null);

                    //construct url
                    String url = "http://beerportfolio.com/app_getAllYourStyles.php?u=" + userID;


                    //todo: async task goes here

                    new PortfolioGetAllStyles(selectedItemView.getContext()).execute(url);

                }

                else if (portfolioChoice.equals("Rating")){

                    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) theLayout.findViewById(R.id.addSpinnerLayout);
                    ll.removeAllViews();
                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)selectedItemView.getContext().getSystemService(selectedItemView.getContext().LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.addspinner_layout, null); // inflate addspinner
                    Spinner sp = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.portfolioSpinner2); //portfolioSpinner2
                    ll.addView(v); // add the view to the linear layout

                    //get userID
                    //get user data
                    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(selectedItemView.getContext());
                    String userID = prefs.getString("userID", null);

                    //make array

                    //make array list for beer
                    final List<String> tasteList = new ArrayList<String>();
                    tasteList.add("1");
                    tasteList.add("2");
                    tasteList.add("3");
                    tasteList.add("4");
                    tasteList.add("5");

                    // Selection of the spinner
                    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) theLayout.findViewById(R.id.portfolioSpinner2);

                    // Application of the Array to the Spinner
                    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(selectedItemView.getContext(),   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,tasteList );
                    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); // The drop down view
                    spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);



                    //todo: add on select for spinner 2
//add on item selected
                    final Spinner portfolioType = (Spinner) theLayout.findViewById(R.id.portfolioSpinner2);
                    portfolioType.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {


                        @Override
                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {

                            String portfolioChoice = portfolioType.getSelectedItem().toString();

                            //Toast.makeText(((Activity) c).getApplicationContext(), portfolioChoice, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            final ListView lv = (ListView) theLayout.findViewById(R.id.allYourBeersList);
                            lv.setAdapter(null);

                            //get brewery beers
                            //get userID
                            //get user data
                            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(selectedItemView.getContext());
                            String userID = prefs.getString("userID", null);



                            try {

                                portfolioChoice = URLEncoder.encode(portfolioChoice, "UTF-8");
                            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            //construct url
                            String url = "myURL3";

                            Log.d("portfolio" , url);
                            //async task goes here
                            new PortfolioGetAllBeers(selectedItemView.getContext()).execute(url);

                        }



                        @Override
                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
                            // do nothing
                        }

                    });




                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
                // do nothing
            }

        });






        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return theLayout;

    }

    @Override
    public void onArticleSelected(String bID, String brewery){

        //code to execute on click
        Fragment Fragment_one;
        FragmentManager man= getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction tran = man.beginTransaction();
        Fragment_one = new BeerPage();
        final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("beerIDSent", bID);
        bundle.putString("breweryIDSent", brewery);
        Fragment_one.setArguments(bundle);
        tran.replace(R.id.main, Fragment_one);//tran.
        tran.addToBackStack(null);
        tran.commit();

    }

}
```

Then the async task code is:

```
public class PortfolioGetAllBeers extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    Context c;
    private ProgressDialog Dialog;

    public PortfolioGetAllBeers (Context context)
    {
        c = context;
        Dialog = new ProgressDialog(c);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return readJSONFeed(arg0[0]);
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Dialog.setMessage("Getting beers");

        Dialog.setTitle("Loading");
        Dialog.setCancelable(false);
        Dialog.show();
    }

    //***************************code for on click
    OnArticleSelectedListener listener;
    public interface OnArticleSelectedListener{
        public void onArticleSelected(String myString , String brewery);

    }
    public void setOnArticleSelectedListener(OnArticleSelectedListener listener){
        this.listener = listener;


    }
    //*****************************end code for onClick

    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        //decode json here
        try{
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);


            //acces listview
            ListView lv = (ListView) ((Activity) c).findViewById(R.id.allYourBeersList);

            //make array list for beer
            final List<ShortBeerInfo> tasteList = new ArrayList<ShortBeerInfo>();



            for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                String beer = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("beer");
                String rate = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("rate");
                String beerID = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("id");
                String bID = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("breweryID");


                //create object
                ShortBeerInfo tempTaste = new ShortBeerInfo(beer, rate, beerID, bID);

                //add to arraylist
                tasteList.add(tempTaste);
            }


            //add items to listview
            ShortBeerInfoAdapter adapter1 = new ShortBeerInfoAdapter(c ,R.layout.brewer_stats_listview, tasteList);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter1);

            //set up clicks
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                    ShortBeerInfo o=(ShortBeerInfo)arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);

                    String tempID = o.id;
                    String tempBrewID = o.brewery;


                    //todo: go to beer page
                    listener.onArticleSelected(tempID, tempBrewID);


                }
            });

        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }

        Dialog.dismiss();

    }

    public String readJSONFeed(String URL) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line);
                }
                inputStream.close();
            } else {
                Log.d("JSON", "Failed to download file");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("readJSONFeed", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

}
```

***Updated Code:***

```
public class Portfolio extends Fragment implements PortfolioGetAllBeers.OnArticleSelectedListener {

    String beerId = "";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //set layout here
        final View theLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_portfolio, container, false);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        getActivity().setTitle("Style");

        //get user information
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        String userName = prefs.getString("userName", null);
        String userID = prefs.getString("userID", null);

        final Spinner portfolioType = (Spinner) theLayout.findViewById(R.id.portfolioSpinner);
        portfolioType.OnArticleSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {


            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {

                String portfolioChoice = portfolioType.getSelectedItem().toString();


                Log.d("portfolio", portfolioChoice);

                if( portfolioChoice.equals("All")){


                    //todo: clear second spinner
                    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) theLayout.findViewById(R.id.addSpinnerLayout);
                    ll.removeAllViews();

                    //get userID
                    //get user data
                    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(selectedItemView.getContext());
                    String userID = prefs.getString("userID", null);

                    //construct url
                    String url = "myURL";


                    //async task goes here
                    PortfolioGetAllBeers task = new PortfolioGetAllBeers(getActivity());
                    task.setOnArticleSelectedListener(this);
                    task.execute(url);

                }

                else if (portfolioChoice.equals("Brewery")){

                    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) theLayout.findViewById(R.id.addSpinnerLayout);
                    ll.removeAllViews();
                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)selectedItemView.getContext().getSystemService(selectedItemView.getContext().LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.addspinner_layout, null); // inflate addspinner
                    Spinner sp = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.portfolioSpinner2); //portfolioSpinner2
                    ll.addView(v); // add the view to the linear layout

                    //todo: get breweries and fill spinner
                    //get userID
                    //get user data
                    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(selectedItemView.getContext());
                    String userID = prefs.getString("userID", null);

                    //construct url
                    String url = "myURL";


                    //async task goes here
                    new PortfolioGetAllBreweries(selectedItemView.getContext()).execute(url);

                }


                else if (portfolioChoice.equals("Style")){

                    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) theLayout.findViewById(R.id.addSpinnerLayout);
                    ll.removeAllViews();
                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)selectedItemView.getContext().getSystemService(selectedItemView.getContext().LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.addspinner_layout, null); // inflate addspinner
                    Spinner sp = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.portfolioSpinner2); //portfolioSpinner2
                    ll.addView(v); // add the view to the linear layout

                    //get userID
                    //get user data
                    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(selectedItemView.getContext());
                    String userID = prefs.getString("userID", null);

                    //construct url
                    String url = "http://beerportfolio.com/app_getAllYourStyles.php?u=" + userID;


                    //todo: async task goes here

                    new PortfolioGetAllStyles(selectedItemView.getContext()).execute(url);

                }

                else if (portfolioChoice.equals("Rating")){

                    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) theLayout.findViewById(R.id.addSpinnerLayout);
                    ll.removeAllViews();
                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)selectedItemView.getContext().getSystemService(selectedItemView.getContext().LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.addspinner_layout, null); // inflate addspinner
                    Spinner sp = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.portfolioSpinner2); //portfolioSpinner2
                    ll.addView(v); // add the view to the linear layout

                    //get userID
                    //get user data
                    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(selectedItemView.getContext());
                    String userID = prefs.getString("userID", null);

                    //make array

                    //make array list for beer
                    final List<String> tasteList = new ArrayList<String>();
                    tasteList.add("1");
                    tasteList.add("2");
                    tasteList.add("3");
                    tasteList.add("4");
                    tasteList.add("5");

                    // Selection of the spinner
                    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) theLayout.findViewById(R.id.portfolioSpinner2);

                    // Application of the Array to the Spinner
                    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(selectedItemView.getContext(),   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,tasteList );
                    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); // The drop down view
                    spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);



                    //todo: add on select for spinner 2
//add on item selected
                    final Spinner portfolioType = (Spinner) theLayout.findViewById(R.id.portfolioSpinner2);
                    portfolioType.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {


                        @Override
                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {

                            String portfolioChoice = portfolioType.getSelectedItem().toString();

                            //Toast.makeText(((Activity) c).getApplicationContext(), portfolioChoice, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            final ListView lv = (ListView) theLayout.findViewById(R.id.allYourBeersList);
                            lv.setAdapter(null);

                            //get brewery beers
                            //get userID
                            //get user data
                            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(selectedItemView.getContext());
                            String userID = prefs.getString("userID", null);



                            try {

                                portfolioChoice = URLEncoder.encode(portfolioChoice, "UTF-8");
                            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            //construct url
                            String url = "myURL2";

                            Log.d("portfolio" , url);
                            //async task goes here
                            new PortfolioGetAllBeers(selectedItemView.getContext()).execute(url);

                        }



                        @Override
                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
                            // do nothing
                        }

                    });




                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
                // do nothing
            }

        });






        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return theLayout;

    }

    @Override
    public void onArticleSelected(String bID, String brewery){

        //code to execute on click
        Fragment Fragment_one;
        FragmentManager man= getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction tran = man.beginTransaction();
        Fragment_one = new BeerPage();
        final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("beerIDSent", bID);
        bundle.putString("breweryIDSent", brewery);
        Fragment_one.setArguments(bundle);
        tran.replace(R.id.main, Fragment_one);//tran.
        tran.addToBackStack(null);
        tran.commit();

    }

}
```

Comment: The easiest way to communicate between your activity and your asynctask would be to create one interface, add the methods you need inside it, and then inside onPostExecute(), call them using a try/catch block. In the activity, implement the interface and override the methods (instead of using setSOmeInterfaceListener). That will hopefully help here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quick fix is to simply change this line

task.setOnArticleSelectedListener(this);

to

task.setOnArticleSelectedListener(Portfolio.this);

---

Explanation:

You instantiated an inline definition of the AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener with the line

portfolioType.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {...}

so when you are calling setOnArticleSelectedListener() you are doing it within this inline class definition. Thus 'this' is not understood by the compiler as the current instance of Portfolio, but rather as the current instance of AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener. However inline definition has access to enclosing Portfolio class and its members. With the use of 'Portfolio.this' you tell the compiler to use current instance of this enclosing class.

Comment: just realized this fixed one problem but I can not use this for other async tasks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22155201/using-an-interface-from-multiple-async-tasks

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation of `PortfolioGetAllBeers` task has a method `setOnArticleSelectedListener()` which takes an `OnArticleSelectedListener` instance as an argument.

Howerver, in the line that's generating the error, you're passing an object of type `AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener`:

Here is a line where you're creating a listener of this type:

```
portfolioType.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() { ...
```

Then inside this scope you're calling:

```
PortfolioGetAllBeers task = new PortfolioGetAllBeers(getActivity());
task.setOnArticleSelectedListener(this);
```

In this scope, `this` refers to the `AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener` object, which is not what your task expects. Based on your code, it looks like you want your task to call back to the `Portfolio` fragment since it's the one that implements the callback method of your listener interface.

So the way to indicate to the compiler that you want `this` to mean the `Portfolio` instance is to write it like this:

```
task.setOnArticleSelectedListener(Portfolio.this);
```

Now you're passing the correct object instance your task.

Comment: changed that line to OnArticleSelectedListened from setONItemSelectedLIstener and now I am getting:

Cannot resolve method 'OnArticleSelectedListener(android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener)

Comment: I think you may have changed the wrong line. You're calling `OnArticleSelectedListener()` on a `Spinner` object, which doesn't have that method. It has a method called `setOnItemSelectedListener()`. I'm going to update my answer with more details.